# AWS S3 Console - Not working today

Tags: amazon-s3

Is anyone having trouble with the AWS S3 console today?  Any browser / region?

It appears that they are trying to switch over to a new UI, but most of the students in my class get "Internal Error" on their browser.  All other service UIs seem fine.

Some were able to get past the buggy UI, but could not create buckets - even clearly unique names were found to be non-unique.

Is it a holiday in Seattle today?

Comment: Yes, there was an outage. Even SO was affected

Comment: AWS Console is not working since yesterday and I have to process my payment. All I am hoping is that the services don't get discontinued. Is there any other way to process the payment?

Answer (score 1):

aws s3 is giving problems in US-EAST-1. Here is a quote from their service help dashboard.

> Increased Error Rates
>
> Update at 10:33 AM PST: We're continuing to work to remediate the
>   availability issues for Amazon S3 in US-EAST-1. AWS services and
>   customer applications depending on S3 will continue to experience high
>   error rates as we are actively working to remediate the errors in
>   Amazon S3.

Personally, I have 3 different amazon accounts (not in US-EAST-1) and i cannot access s3 in any of them via the console

Answer (score -1):

Yup, it was a biggie.  Didn't hit the news until after my post.  What was really interesting is AWS's service dashboard didn't update accurately, because it was stored on S3!
Here's a cute video of an AWS presenter getting caught during the outage:  http://bgr.com/2017/02/28/internet-outage-amazon-awsome-day-aws/